# How do I align these equations by the first letter?

Tags: formatting

This code is only for use on stackexchange, it's not a document. Unsure of how to align these equations.

codereview.stackexchange only supports mathjaxx in $$..$$ format not $..$.

```
$$
  \lambda = 
    \small{
      \text{[m]}
    }
    \tiny{
      \text{metres}
    }
$$

$$
  \text{E} = 
    \small{
      \text{[J]}
    }
    \tiny{
      \text{joules}
    }
$$

$$
  \text{h} =
    \small{
      \text{[J]} 
    }
    \tiny{
      \text{joules}
    }\cdot
    \small{
      [\text{s}^{\tiny{-1}}]
    }
    \tiny{
      \text{seconds}
    }
$$

$$
  \text{c} =
    \small{
      \text{[m]} 
    }
    \tiny{
      \text{metres}
    }\cdot
    \small{
      [\text{s}^{\tiny{-1}}]
    }
    \tiny{
      \text{seconds}
    }
$$

$$
  N_A = 
    \small{
      [\text{mol}^{\tiny{-1}}]
    }
    \tiny{
      \text{Avogadro's number}
    }
$$

$$
  \text{c} = 
    \small{
      299792600\ 
      \text{m} \cdot \text{s}^{-1}
    }
$$

$$
  N_A =  
    \small{
      6.0221415\ \cdot\ 10^{23}
    }
$$

$$
  \text{h} = 
    \small{
      6.62607600\ \cdot\ 10^{-34}\ 
      \text{J} \cdot \text{s}^{-1}
    }
$$
```

It is not displaying here, maybe the site requires it in document format?

#### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: size commands like `\small` do not take an argument so `\small xz` not `\small {xyz}` and they may not be used in math mode. (note mathjax specific questions are off topic here)

Comment: use `\begin{align}` to align equations (it works in mathjax)

Comment: thanks @DavidCarlisle I'll try that, and sorry I thought this was for all latex type stuff

Comment: on stackexchange you have to use \small{} like a function with args

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't think I can align that way as the mathjaxx in stackexchange is started with $$..$$ rather than being a document, at least in the other stackexchanges.

Comment: No you can use align (or align in $$)

Comment: I got it working by adding `\end{align}` however everything is on one line I use `\\ ` for a newline, is the formatting of my code messing things up?

Comment: see `align*` here on math.stackexchange https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4730480/78428

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use size commands in math, and they do not take an argument.

You want `align*` here

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \lambda &= 
      \mathrm{[m]}
      _{\mathrm{metres}}
\\
  \mathrm{E} &= 
      \mathrm{[J]}
      _{\mathrm{joules}}
\\
  \mathrm{h} &=
      \mathrm{[J]} 
      _{\mathrm{joules}}
    \cdot
      [\mathrm{s}^{-1}]
      _{\mathrm{seconds}}
\\
  \mathrm{c} &=
      \mathrm{[m]} 
      _{\mathrm{metres}}
    \cdot
      [\mathrm{s}^{-1}]
      _{\mathrm{seconds}}
\\
  N_A &= 
      [\mathrm{mol}^{-1}]
      _{\mathrm{Avogadro's\ number}}
\\
  \mathrm{c} &= 
      299792600 
      \mathrm{m} \cdot \mathrm{s}^{-1}
\\
  N_A &=  
      6.0221415 \cdot 10^{23}
\\
  \mathrm{h} &= 
      6.62607600 \cdot 10^{-34}  
      \mathrm{J} \cdot \mathrm{s}^{-1}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the reason I changed sizes is because of the formatting issues look at the \cdot with seconds, this is much cleaner, I'll write my mathjaxx like this, thank you. Very nice formatting I thought everyone just wrote the code in one line.

Comment: @Nickotine I don't understand the comment, but anyway they are a syntax error (mathjax only has one x)

Comment: look at how the variables in [] align with the text, and compare to my screenshot then look at `h=` and `c=` the \cdot doesn't align properly to seconds. Compare my screenshot to your output you'll see they're different. I was just complimenting you on how good  and readable your code looks, usually examples I've seen have everything in one line with the $$..$$ syntax

Comment: well I just learned I'm not using real latex/mathjaxx (depending on which you wrote) much appreciated, can you help me out with the variable formatting problem I mentioned?

Comment: @Nickotine you are using mathjax, but mathjax is javascript not tex

Comment: ok I'm going to start using tex as it's much cleaner, can you help me out to have your output look like mine, I mean for the equations, the aligning for the first letters is solved

Comment: @Nickotine your image looked weird and I had to guess the syntax you intended with `\small{..` so I guessed subscript but I've never seen a syntax with `m` and `metres` used at the same time so I had to guess

Comment: @Nickotine ??? you can't use tex on a stackexchange site, you need to use mathjax. (on this site you can  not use either)

Comment: I defined it like that as I'm going to post it in codereview.stackexchange so that people can know what `m` all the symbols mean. It's  just a one off. When you have `[var]<text>` the text is low down on `[]` and the \cdot for `h=` and `c=` are high up.

Comment: what is the code you wrote written in?

Comment: @Nickotine I wrote a latex document and showed the image of latex output. But (just) the `align*` environment is supported by the javascript emulation of latex math in mathjax, so you can copy that part into a mathjax enabled web page

Comment: think I'm not explaining myself properly but compare your `[m]metres` etc, formatting and the \cdots for the variables h and c, they all look off, compare the equation contents to mine then you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Nickotine the cdot are vertically aligned on the =. As I say I put `metres` in a subscript but if you don't like that remove the `_`  I think it is pretty confusing syntax either way.

Comment: please compare both of our outputs. for seconds the \cdot isn't correctly formatted it goes up , for the boxes the text aligns write at the bottom of the box, you'll see it if you compare our outputs

Comment: I want to keep the subscript, like I said I only use this syntax once as the audience won't know the meaning of the symbol, do you see the difference in our outputs?

Comment: @Nickotine sure you have inconsistent cdot: small misplaced low ones for line 3 and 4, and normal cdot on lines 6,7,8. I assumed that was in error and I used a normal cdot on all lines.