# I'm using subscripts, how do I to format \cdot and [var]<subscript> correctly using latex?

Tags: formatting

Following on from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/690297/how-do-i-align-these-equations-by-the-first-letter/690300?noredirect=1#comment1713002_690300)

My alignment of the first letters was solved. However all variables that have a subscript, have the subscripts too far down example; `[x]<subscript text>`

Also my \cdots are formatted too high.

Compare my screenshot to the output given by the answer I linked.

#### Screen shot of my equations and mathjaxx code

code:

```
$
  \lambda = 
    \small{
      \text{[m]}
    }
    \tiny{
      \text{metres}
    }
$$

$$
  \text{E} = 
    \small{
      \text{[J]}
    }
    \tiny{
      \text{joules}
    }
$$

$$
  \text{h} =
    \small{
      \text{[J]} 
    }
    \tiny{
      \text{joules}
    }\cdot
    \small{
      [\text{s}^{\tiny{-1}}]
    }
    \tiny{
      \text{seconds}
    }
$$

$$
  \text{c} =
    \small{
      \text{[m]} 
    }
    \tiny{
      \text{metres}
    }\cdot
    \small{
      [\text{s}^{\tiny{-1}}]
    }
    \tiny{
      \text{seconds}
    }
$$

$$
  N_A = 
    \small{
      [\text{mol}^{\tiny{-1}}]
    }
    \tiny{
      \text{Avogadro's number}
    }
$$

$$
  \text{c} = 
    \small{
      299792600\ 
      \text{m} \cdot \text{s}^{-1}
    }
$$

$$
  N_A =  
    \small{
      6.0221415\ \cdot\ 10^{23}
    }
$$

$$
  \text{h} = 
    \small{
      6.62607600\ \cdot\ 10^{-34}\ 
      \text{J} \cdot \text{s}^{-1}
    }
$$
```

[image]

code and output given by last answer I linked:

```latex
documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \lambda &= 
      \mathrm{[m]}
      _{\mathrm{metres}}
\\
  \mathrm{E} &= 
      \mathrm{[J]}
      _{\mathrm{joules}}
\\
  \mathrm{h} &=
      \mathrm{[J]} 
      _{\mathrm{joules}}
    \cdot
      [\mathrm{s}^{-1}]
      _{\mathrm{seconds}}
\\
  \mathrm{c} &=
      \mathrm{[m]} 
      _{\mathrm{metres}}
    \cdot
      [\mathrm{s}^{-1}]
      _{\mathrm{seconds}}
\\
  N_A &= 
      [\mathrm{mol}^{-1}]
      _{\mathrm{Avogadro's\ number}}
\\
  \mathrm{c} &= 
      299792600 
      \mathrm{m} \cdot \mathrm{s}^{-1}
\\
  N_A &=  
      6.0221415 \cdot 10^{23}
\\
  \mathrm{h} &= 
      6.62607600 \cdot 10^{-34}  
      \mathrm{J} \cdot \mathrm{s}^{-1}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toEUe.png):

I want to have the same formatting after `=` from my screenshot, the boxed variables which have subscripts and \cdots using latex.

#### Update

just 1 minor issue with subscripts.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BzpZDnCk6Ypk9zxuy7vcnEUmY898ah_8/view?usp=drivesdk

The lower part of the subscripted letter goes a little bit under my variable box.

The code for each of these equations in order of the screenshot are:

```
$$[j]_{\text{joules}}$$
$$[j]\small{\text{joules}}$$
$$[j]\tiny{\text{joules}}$$
```

Is there a way where I could have the subscripted version (first one formatted like the others?

Or a better way to write the last 2?

I know it's really minor but I'm just that type of guy.

Comment: the correct version is as I posted. You have  `\tiny{  \text{joules}  }\cdot`  which is `\tiny \text{joules} \cdot` so a tiny cdot which makes no sense  as the expression is h=J ⋅ S

Comment: I already explained why I have the variables the way I do and h=j *s^-1, so it makes sense, all I want is for the \cdots to format properly and the subscript on the boxed variable to appear just like my screenshot, not lower like in yours.

Comment: could you please see my screenshot and compare forget about my code being wrong I just want the same formatting

Comment: you're answer is correct but many things don't align properly.

Comment: subscript means lower, if you don't want it lower remove the `_` as I suggested before.

Comment: I don't see your double joules, anywhere in the code or output

Comment: "double joues" ???

Comment: I do want it lower and smaller but want the  \cdot to line up properly instead of going high

Comment: ```tiny{  \text{joules}  }\cdot which is \tiny \text{joules``` don't see this anywhere in my code

Comment: I'm just asking if you know how to format everything after `=` the way I have done it.

Comment: the cdot is completely unchanged by the subscript it is the same size and same vertical position as the rows without. Put it _in_ the subcript if you want it small and low as in your original, but that obscures the meaning

Comment: you have that in rows 3 and 4 that is why those rows have tiny cdot in your original

Comment: it's not about the size of the \cdot it's that the cdot is so high up, so I guess the solution is to subscript the \cdot. For [x]<subscript text> the subscript text is much to low on the box you can see a clear difference in that when you compare our outputs, do you have a latex solution to format my variable boxes with subscripts exactly how I done it in mathjaxx?

Comment: I had to use tiny on the \cdots otherwise they would be misaligned I'd actually prefer them to be bigger but aligned properly

Comment: if you  want to have any chance the reader understands the expression `h=J ⋅ S` and  `h=J_x ⋅ S_x` should have the same dot at the same vertical position.

Comment: that saves me a lot of typing but I just have 1 very minor issue with it which I've added in the description. Could you please take a look?

Comment: maybe write an answer in latex so I can give credit as you've been very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two separate issues with your equations.

- If you do not like the output of `_{\mathrm{...}}`, I suggest you write `\textsubscript{...}` instead -- the more so as the subscript materials aren't really *mathematical* subscripts but, rather, textual side-notes.

  If the output of `\textsubscript` is too large for your taste, do use `\tinytextsubscript` instead, where `\tinytextsubscript` should be defined in the preamble as

  ```
  \newcommand\tinytextsubscript[1]{\textsubscript{\tiny #1}}
  ```
- You really should switch to using the `\num`, `\unit`, and `\qty` macros of the [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package to denote scientific quantities and their associated units. That way, you'll separate the *content matters* much more effectively and cleanly from *formatting matters*.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for align* env.
\usepackage{siunitx} % for \num, \unit, and \qty macros
\sisetup{group-digits=false,
         exponent-product={\cdot},  % default is '\times'
         inter-unit-product={\cdot} % optional
        }
\newcommand\avo{N_{\!A}} % snug up "A" to "N"
\newcommand\tinytextsubscript[1]{\textsubscript{\tiny #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \lambda &= [\unit{\metre}]\tinytextsubscript{metres}  \\
  E       &= [\unit{\joule}]\tinytextsubscript{joules}\\
  h       &= [\unit{\joule}]\tinytextsubscript{joules}
             \cdot
             [\unit{\per\second}]\tinytextsubscript{per second} \\
  c       &= [\unit{\metre}]\tinytextsubscript{metres}
             \cdot
             [\unit{\per\second}]\tinytextsubscript{per second} \\
  \avo    &= [\unit{\per\mol}]\tinytextsubscript{Avogadro's number} \\[1.5ex]
  c       &= \qty{299792600}{\metre\per\second} \\
  \avo    &= \num{6.0221415e23} \\
  h       &= \qty{6.62607600e-34}{\joule\per\second} 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm new to latex I've only used mathjaxx on stackexchange with the `$..$` notation I like this style very much, thanks a lot. How do you upload the output to stack.imgr?

Comment: also for `per/second` is there a way i can get the `^-1` to be smaller?

Comment: `newcommand\tinytextsubscript[1]{\textsubscript{\tiny #1}}` is this how you declare 'functions' in latex for example `newcommand\anyName[input]\{\<latex cmd>}{<latexCmdInput> input}`?

Comment: @Nickotine - I recommend you peruse the user guide of the [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package to study how the `\per` directive can be deployed. Please see any introductory document on LaTeX, such as [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) by Tobias Oetiker and others, for information on how to define LaTeX macros. TeX is a macro expansion language at heart; hence, it's better to talk about "macros" than about "functions".

Comment: macros, functions, you know I mean something that takes an input does something to that input and gives an output, thanks for the source

Comment: nothing on commands in that laTeX book mostly formatting stuff and I can't find anything on how to lower the size of the power using your source on `per`

Comment: cdots don't format properly, powers don't match text size of x (pseudo code) `\small{y} \normal{\cdot} \small{x}^\normal{-1}` if these all could be resolved I'd switch to using complete laTeX with your style of coding

Comment: @Nickotine - I don't follow what you're saying. How or where is `\normal` defined? `\small` is a text-mode command (for a ca 10% linear font size reduction) and will definitely *not* work in math mode. What is "match" in "powers don't match text size" supposed to mean? In my opinion (and what TeX does...), exponents should *always* be rendered ca 30% (linearly) *smaller* than the associated base. `\cdot` is placed on the math center line, at the same height as `+` and `-`. If you can't stand these basic formatting guidelines, TeX and LaTeX are certainly not the right typesetting tool for you.

Comment: I can't subscript the `per` and I wanted the cdot on the same level as the description text, but I like the way this is written

Comment: @Nickotine - Then why don't you use `.` instead of `\cdot` (and, incidentally, willfully ignore just about every known convention of math typesetting)? The whole essence of `\cdot` is to create a dot that's raised above the baseline.

Comment: what about subscripting per? the cdot would just be a little lower than normal not at baseline. I can do what I want just not with the si units stuff which I like

Comment: @Nickotine - I think that would be *truly horrific* idea. Have you followed up on my eaerlier suggestion to peruse the user guide of the `siunitx` package to learn more about how `\per` might be used. E.g., have you tried the option (to be stated as an argument of `\sisetup`) `per-mode=symbol`?

Comment: you know what I'm over complicating things just for looks, I'll just stop as it's giving me a headache

Comment: thank you for this example, as I do a lot of this kind of stuff, the si units  and macro definition are really good things I got from you

Comment: Last question, where do you post your LaTeX to get the pdf? I'm on iphone and the app I have is buggy

Comment: @Nickotine - I use a MacBook Air that runs MacOS 13.4.1 "Ventura", and my TeX distribution is MacTeX2023 (with all updates applied). pdfLaTeX creates a pdf file by default.